# Writing to File Exception?

Tags: java, file, exception, tokenize

I'm having the user of my program enter information in a `JOptionPane` after pressing a button in a GUI. The information is written to a text file. I would like to have an exception happen and a message appear if the information they enter is not the right amount of tokens.

I've split up each line of the file with the string tokenizer, and each line has seven tokens, which the delimiter being a comma. So if the user lets say enters only three tokens, I would like an error message displayed.

Having trouble with this one, any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?  And note that "Writing to File Exception??" is **not** a question.

Comment: @HFOE -1 'code', +1 '[SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)'.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew: sure an SSCCE is optimal, but heck at this point I'd take anything.

Answer (score 4):

**I would say exceptions are for EXCEPTIONAL situations**. This seams like error checking 101.

Just check if the user has the correct amount of tokens and show him the desired error.

Don't over complicate things.

Comment: Totally agree, no need to use excepts for flow control.